# Pass EXEC command as a variable into .sql

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, stored-procedures

**CURRENT STATE:**
I have a batch script (mybatch.bat) that calls a stored procedure via a .sql file (file.sql) and currently passes three variables to it - the stored procedure and two parameters. The .sql currently outputs a variable based on this stored procedure.:

*file.sql*

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec &1('&2', '&3', :out_val);
print out_val
exit
```

*mybatch.bat*

```
set procedure=%1
set param1=%2
set param2=%3
set strYN = ' '

rem ** This line stores out_val value Y or N as strYN.
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlplus database/pw@user @"file.sql" %procedure% %param1% %param2%`) do (
    set stryn=%%i
    if /I "!strYN!"=="N" (goto:nextN) else (if /I "!strYN!"=="Y" goto:nextY)
)
```

**PROBLEM:**
I want to be able to call other stored procedures from this same .sql file that might **not** have output variables (out_val). So I'd like to be able to concatenate the execution line within my batch and pass it as a variable to the .sql

**FUTURE STATE:**
I'd like to be able to pass the entire command into my .sql as a variable like so:

*file.sql*

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec &1
print out_val
exit
```

*mybatch.bat*

```
set procedure=%1
set param1=%2
set param2=%3
set strYN = ' '
set command=%procedure%('%param1%', '%param2%', :out_val);

rem ** This line stores out_val value Y or N as strYN.
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlplus database/pw@user @"file.sql" %command%`) do (
    set stryn=%%i
    if /I "!strYN!"=="N" (goto:nextN) else (if /I "!strYN!"=="Y" goto:nextY)
)
```

Is this possible? Or can .sql variables only be used as parameters? Perhaps there's a sql function that accepts variables as a line to be executed?

Comment: You can use a substitution variable with `exec`; `exec &1` works. Do you have a reason to think it doesn't, or a specific problem with what you're trying to do? The only obvious issue with what you have now is that you'd be passing several arguments, so you'd need `"%command%"`; but you haven't said if you're getting an error.

Comment: I'm not receiving an error during the run, but the batch hangs on the execute command. I think this is because the data being passed in is not being executed properly. But I've coded the current and future states in separate batches/.sqls. The current state works properly, but future state does not.

Comment: I would expect it to error, not hang, is `%command%` isn't enclosed in double-quotes. (Don't have SQL*Plus on Windows handy to test with). It might appear to hang if the credentials are wrong - hard to tell if they're the same as you've hidden them, of course, but if you add a `-l` flag that can avoid it re-prompting for credentials if they are wrong. Do either of those things make a difference? Might need to use double-quotes both when setting `%command%` and when passing it as an argument.

Comment: I actually found out the answer! It's because I included the semicolon in the batch variable. It should have been: exec &1; 

So I removed the semicolon from the command variable and put quotes around it when passing it into the sql file and it works!

Comment: OK, I was trying it without a semicolon after the passed command or after the `&1`. It doesn't seem to matter if the `exec` has one. But if the command does then it errors, whether `exec` has one too or not. But don't see why that would hang for you. Still, good you got it sorted *8-) And remember you can answer your own question (and accept that answer) if you think someone else might find that useful one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was regarding the semicolon at the end of my %command% variable's value. I removed the semicolon from the value of the variable and added it to the end of the exec command in the .sql file. I also wrapped the %command% parameter pass in quotes because the variable contained spaces.

*file.sql*

```
set serveroutput on
variable out_val varchar2;
exec &1;
print out_val
exit
```

*mybatch.bat*

```
set procedure=%1
set param1=%2
set param2=%3
set strYN = ' '
set command=%procedure%('%param1%', '%param2%', :out_val)

rem ** This line stores out_val value Y or N as strYN.
for /F "usebackq" %%i in (`sqlplus database/pw@user @"file.sql" "%command%"`) do (
    set stryn=%%i
    if /I "!strYN!"=="N" (goto:nextN) else (if /I "!strYN!"=="Y" goto:nextY)
)
```